# VBA: Highlight a row with a specific column value

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a very large excel 2010 workbook with several sheets.

One of the sheets is called `"RatePlan"` and one of the columns in this sheet is `"RatePlanCde"`.

Some of these `"RatePlanCde"` (a total of 2514) are not valid anymore and have been highlighted in Red.

I need to find if `"RatePlanCde"` column exists in any other sheets. If so, then highlight the row with the invalid `"RatePlanCde"` value in all the sheets in Red too.

Can this be done using a VBA script and how?

Comment: Of course this can be done with VBA, but why don't you try to use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking at this option now. Looks like conditional formatting rules with formula should be used to achieve this and needs be done on all the sheets in the workbook individually. Invalid RatePlanCde is a random value (not in a specific range). So, I think if I use Conditional Formatting on all the sheets with a Formula that says if RatePlanCde is equal to and paste all 2514 invalid values here, it should solve my problem.

Comment: If you would add a column next to RatePlanCde-codes and mark the invalid with for example a string "invalid", you could use a `VLookup` formula in the conditional formatting.

Comment: I have added a helper column to sheet "RatePlan" with a string valid/ invalid for the corresponding RatePlanCde. Now in the Sheet 2, I want to use conditional formatting with Vlookup to highlight the rows where RatePlanCde is invalid. Could you please help? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Formula for conditional formatting is a simple `VLookup`

The following formula assumes that the codes in the *"other"* sheets is in Col A, the codes are in the Rateplan-Sheet in Col C and the "INVALID"-marker in COl D:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;RatePlan!$C$2:$D2515;2;FALSE)="INVALID"
```